# Can I add a callback function to the legend while keeping the original functionality?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a simple line graph made with chartjs with a legend. By default, when the user clicks the legend then it shows/hides the dataset that the user clicked. I have a callback function that I would like to call, but when I assign the callback function to the legend, then the original functionality of showing/hiding the datasets is not present anymore. Is there a way for me to add my callback function without getting rid of the default functionality? Below is how my current legend onClick looks, "vm.legendOnclickCallback()" simply calls a console.log statement for now, for testing. My filter function is used to get rid of a bar (named dayBar) from the legend.

```
legend: {
        labels: {
               filter: function (item, chart) {
                    return !item.text.includes('dayBar');
                }
        },
        onClick: vm.legendOnclickCallback
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html) show how to do this. You can call the default handler in your custom function:

```
var defaultLegendClickHandler = Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick;
defaultLegendClickHandler(e, legendItem);
```